# (DB first)I have added one more tables in database after Scaffold. Now trying to add those tables into my model in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have tried it, but it create a master context do not add any new tables into model.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -OutputDir Models -Tables OrderDetails -f
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the scaffold command you show, you're scaffolding the Master database. That's probably not your application database, or at least it shouldn't be. Master is a system database, and your application should have its own database.

You could add the new tables manually as EF core model classes.

Comment: thanks, it was my mistake but how is it possible to update specific one. if I provide table name in package manager console then it remove others model..